# Remove Preferences menu item on OS X apps

Tags: macos, wxpython

When using wxPython, is it possible to remove or disable the "Preferences" menu item that gets automatically created in the Python menu on OS X?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the benefit of others that may run into this, I figured out the solution: "wx.App_SetMacPreferencesMenuItemId(wx.ID_NONE)". The trick is to do this before you create the menu, not after. On wxPython 2.9.1.1 it will ghost out the Preferences menu item (which is good enough for me). On 2.9.2 it will remove the item completely.